# Is there a way to update and show a field in Azure application insight request body using KQL?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql

request body:

```
{
name: "SomeName",
insertionTime: "timeInUtc"
}
```

query:

```
requests 
| where url contains "/get"
| extend requestBody = parse_json(customDimensions["Request-Body"]) 
| project requestBody
```

I want to show the request body with updated timestamp in the results table. like timestamp plus 2 hours.

I want to use this request body with new stamp so that I can retry the same requests again with new timestamp for failed requests. Im trying to build some automation for failed api calls with new timestamp in the request body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To show the request body with updated timestamp in the results table. like timestamp plus 2 hours:

***You can use the below kql query to achieve the expected results.***

```bash
requests 
| where url contains "/get"
| extend requestBody = parse_json(customDimensions["Request-Body"]) 
| extend latestTimestamp = datetime_add('hour', 2, todatetime(requestBody.insertionTime))
| extend newinsertiontime = tostring(latestTimestamp)
| project newinsertiontime
```

*As I do not have any results in the given time stamp, I got the below expected output.*

[image]

You can use [pack_array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/packarrayfunction) to combine all the results with the name, insertion time as well as new insertion time as detailed in the given MSDoc.

Comment: This was helpful. But could have used replace_string itself. No need to make it complex like this.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming that you are aware that you of course cannot update the actual stored data in the table).

In your query you can do any kind of mathematical operations that you like:

```
requests 
| where url contains "/get"
| extend requestBody = parse_json(customDimensions["Request-Body"]) 
| project SalaryExtended=toint(requestBody.salary)
| extend IncreasedSalary=SalaryExtended+100
```

Comment: Yes, actually I have updated the question to better clarify my requirement. I want to use this request body with new stamp so that I can retry the same requests again with new timestamp for failed requests. Can you help me with this?